# How to get the loop to count 1 every 1 sec in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have written a code that count from 1 to 20 with a start sleep for 5 and then continues. But I need the counter to count 1 every second, so the entire loop takes 25 sec to run. Right now it only take like 7-9 sec.

```
$counter = 0
for ($counter -lt 20)
{
    Start-sleep 0
    $Counter++
    write-host $Counter
    if ($Counter -eq 10)
    {
        Start-sleep 5
    }
    If ($Counter -eq 20)
    {
        Break
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example isn't very clear; you want each iteration of the loop to take one second?  `1..10 | % { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 }`

Comment: I have edited my question a bit, hope that it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A stopwatch could be used to keep the time better.
Once you reach the thresold (10 seconds), you have to restart it.

The only downside to this approach is that if you are at 7 seconds and then you are doing something in the loop that take 5 seconds, you will reach the 10 seconds loop at 12 seconds (hence why I used -ge as condition).

```
$StopWatch = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch'
$StopWatch.Start()

For ($Counter = 0;$counter -lt 20) {
    Write-Host '.' -NoNewline
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500 

    if ($StopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds -ge 10) {
        Write-Host ''
        Write-Host "$($StopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds) seconds elapsed... " -ForegroundColor Cyan
        $StopWatch.Restart()
    }

}
```

Alternatively, you could put your main stuff in a job, so even if it takes 2 minutes to complete, the 10 seconds loop will still be executed properly.

```
$MainStuffAction = {
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 20
    Write-Host 'Completed !'
}


$MainStuff = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $MainStuffAction 
$StopWatch = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch'
$StopWatch.Start()

while($true) {
    if ($StopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds -ge 10) {
        Write-Host '10 seconds elapsed!' 

        # We only restart the stopwatch at the end to get our full 10 seconds
        $StopWatch.Restart()
    } 
    elseif ($MainStuff.State -ne 'Running') {
        $MainStuff | Receive-Job
        $MainStuff = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $MainStuffAction 
    }

    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500

}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another way to do it. this uses the `while` construct and shows the `$Counter` & `$Stopwatch` values so you can clearly see if it is doing what you want. [*grin*]

```
$Stopwatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::new()
$Stopwatch.Start()

$Counter = 0
# correct for off-by-one
$Threshold = 19
while ($Counter -le $Threshold)
    {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    $Counter ++
    'Counter = {0:D2}, Seconds = {1:D2}' -f $Counter, $Stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds
    if ($Counter -eq 10)
        {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
        '{0} {1:D2} Seconds' -f (' ' * 15), $Stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds
        }
    }

$Stopwatch.Stop()
$Stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
```

output ...

```
Counter = 01, Seconds = 01
Counter = 02, Seconds = 02
Counter = 03, Seconds = 03
Counter = 04, Seconds = 04
Counter = 05, Seconds = 05
Counter = 06, Seconds = 06
Counter = 07, Seconds = 07
Counter = 08, Seconds = 08
Counter = 09, Seconds = 09
Counter = 10, Seconds = 10
                15 Seconds
Counter = 11, Seconds = 16
Counter = 12, Seconds = 17
Counter = 13, Seconds = 18
Counter = 14, Seconds = 19
Counter = 15, Seconds = 20
Counter = 16, Seconds = 21
Counter = 17, Seconds = 22
Counter = 18, Seconds = 23
Counter = 19, Seconds = 24
Counter = 20, Seconds = 25
25.2769325
```